# How do I record linuxsampler's ALSA output on Linux?

Tags: recording

I have successfully connected my piano keyboard to Linuxsampler, loaded a high-quality GIG sampled instrument and outputted to my laptop internal speakers. I've followed the official documentation, namely [the first LSCP script here](http://www.linuxsampler.org/documentation.html).

I can happily hear what I play on the piano keyboard on my laptop internal speakers, with the loaded instrument voice, but how do I record my playing as a WAV or another RAW format? arecord on the same output device does not work. E.g. this:

```
$ arecord -q -D hw:1,0 -t wav -f s16_le -c2 -r44100 test.wav
```

records nothing or, if I bump up the internal mic capture volume, records a lot of noise - hw:1,0 is the correct device (my laptop internal sound card). Is there any way to record linuxsampler with ALSA cleanly? Or alternatively to save linuxsampler output to a file?

Comment: I have tried to send linuxsampler's output to ALSA audio loopback device and record that, but worse: I get nothing.

Comment: I found out it works with JACK using jackrec or jack_capture.

Comment: Are you also running pulseaudio?

Comment: No, I avoid that. I run jack if needed, else nothing.